# Printer drivers

Tags: printing, driver, scanning

I have several macs, at home and office (Macbook Pro and Air).

I have several Canon multipurpose printers as well. The problem is when you attempt to connect the Mac to the Canon printer via USB, it isn't recognized. In the mac printer dialog it says "Contact the printer manufacturer for drivers".

So you go to the Canon website and try to find drivers for the OSX Yosemite / El Cap and they say "Apple includes these drivers".

How can I get my printer / scanner working with my mac?

Printers are Canon MX310 and Canon MG6620

Comment: Are you ok connecting these printers to the network? Is there a print server or print relay involved? That might make it easier than just plugging USB cables and worrying about drivers.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201465 shows the MX310 as no longer supported, though I can't find any reference on there to the MG6620.

Canon appears to have drivers for the MG6620 on their site - http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg6220#DriversAndSoftware